# Button text changing direction, or wrapping

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity, I create 2 or more fragments.
When the activity initially loads, and displays the first fragment, everything displays fine as below image.

[image: Buttons display good]

If I then do a replace fragment, the buttons text changes to a weird layout as below image.
[image: Buttons display bad]

My activity Layout xml;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="package.android.incabandroid.ActivityJavas.PalletStatusActivity">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblpodstats" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/butLinLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TableRow>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnApplyToAll" style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Select for all" />

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnViewTc" style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:text="View TnC's" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnPodStatBack" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Back" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/btnPodStatNext" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Next" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollStatsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblpodstats" android:layout_above="@id/butLinLayout">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/palletStatusLinLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

all I do is replace palletStatusLinLayout with the new fragment.
If I do a setText on one of the buttons, while they are displaying weird, the buttons change and display correctly, the same as the first pic.

Any Help Much Appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: try using setText only, at the start of activity, instead of setting in tha layout file

Comment: I have tried this, did not work, thanks anyway

Comment: Use linear layout weights.. It will work.. don't use table layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use LinearLayouts instead of TableLayout, I always do so.

replace the TableLayout for a:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"> </LinearLayout>
```

and the TableRow for a:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you mean a linear layout with 2 inner linear layouts?